# How to prohibit call of specific functions when using a certain macro

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I have a macro defined more or less like this:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(Name) \
bool Function#Name()
```

This macro is often used with certain functions. Let's call one of them `foo()`.
It is used in several files like this:

```
SOME_MACRO(Hello) {
   //do stuff here
   foo();
   //do more stuff here
}
```

A new macro `FOO_MACRO` that calls `foo` was created. From now on, when people call `SOME_MACRO`, I don't want them to call `foo()` directly. Instead, I want them to make use of `FOO_MACRO`, which is called before and outside `SOME_MACRO`.

The only way I could think of was to create a lambda function named foo inside the calls to `SOME_MACRO`. The newly defined `foo` would then output errors when called.

```
SOME_MACRO(Hello) {
   auto foo = [](){
      //error
   };
   foo(); //should generate error
   //do more stuff here
}
```

I don't actually know if this will compile but even if it works, I will have to do this one by one on every call of `SOME_MACRO`. It's exhausting and the code becomes repetitive.

One thing I did try was to change the `SOME_MACRO` definition into something like this:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(Name) \
lots of stuff here \
namespace {
   void foo () {}
}
bool Function#Name()
```

If I do this, calling foo will generate a compile error due to ambiguity of the call. This accomplishes my goal of not letting people call the function. But the error might be confusing to others. I want to be able to create an error that lets them know "don't call foo! Use FOO_MACRO instead!".

Is there any other way to achieve this? If possible, I really don't want to use the ambiguous call error.

I'm writing this from memory so there might be syntax errors in the sample codes.

Comment: Macros as they are usually used in C are a bad idea in C++. The reason is mainly that (AFAIK) every identifier is subject of `namespace`s except the one of macros. This can produce convoluted errors which are sometimes not easy to understand. (Probably something you really don't wanted to read.) ;-) Actually, I think your solution is not that bad in your situation. If I remember right every compiler I know mentions both occurrences of a duplicated symbol. So, chances are good that a mis-using user ends up in the definition of `SOME_MACRO()` where you can leave your intention as comment.

Comment: @Scheff I was only told to prohibit use of the function and was not involved in creating any of the macros so I didn't really think much about it. Will keep you you said in mind, though! Thanks! If nothing comes up, then yes, I might have to go with that solution and just add a comment as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could have conditional `#include` statements based on some macro. This would include the correct definition of your function.

Have you considered polymorphism instead? This is the usual c++ answer to c macro ugliness